# Let $R\backslash A$

Tags: general-topology, analysis

Let $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be finite and let $U\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ be open. Then $U\backslash A$ is open.

Note that $U\backslash A=U\cap \left( \mathbb{R} \backslash A\right)$. We know that $U$ and $ \mathbb{R} \backslash A$ are open. We need to show that $U\cap \left( \mathbb{R} \backslash A\right)$ is open. How can I show the statement?

Comment: @BAI The complement of $U\cap \left( \mathbb{R} \backslash A\right)$.

Comment: @Kahler Same thing. $U\cap(\mathbb R\setminus A) = U\setminus A$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$(U\setminus A)^c=(U\cap A^c)^c$$
$$=U^c\cup A$$
As $A$ is closed and $U^c$ as well, the result is obvious.

Comment: And actually, you have already reached here when you wrote down "we know that $U$ and $\mathbb R\setminus A$ are open" since **the intersection of open sets is open** (which is a better proof if you are not restricted to use the property of Cauchy sequence involving in the definition of closed sets, which my mind just restricted myself as so).

Comment: Thanks for answer.